# jQuery Mobile Phone-Gap:- Does the Auto-Dividers in list view is working or not?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ipad, jquery-mobile

I have implemented an iphone app using phonegap and jQuery mobile.

I used Auto-Dividers to set the secton heders alphabeticall letters first letter of the list item.

I have included the required plugins from https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/2851

but its not efect on the list view headers.. Even i used Autodivider property true..

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="e" data-autodividers="true">
```

i have a doubt *`even in jQuery documents also they used list-dividers manually`*..

**`Does the auto divider functionality works or not.`**

*if so why not in our app*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is built into jQuery 1.2.
http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/08/01/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-2-0-alpha/